# Issue creating NEVPNManager object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

See the code below.  Whenever I run this code on my iPhone 5c, running iOS 7, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the let manager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager() line.

How would I fix this, or is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance.

```
let manager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
    var p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()
    manager.`protocol` = p

    let pw = "pw";

    p.username = "un"
    p.passwordReference = pw.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    p.serverAddress = "server"
    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.SharedSecret
    //p.sharedSecretReference = getPasscodeNSData("vpnSharedSecret")
    p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
    p.disconnectOnSleep = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because NEVPNManager was added at iOS8 as you can see in this Apple document [NetworkExtension Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/NetworkExtension.html)

> iOS 8.0 API Diffs
>
> NEVPNManager.h (Added)
>
> Added NEVPNManager
>
> Added NEVPNManager.connection
>
> Added NEVPNManager.enabled
>
> Added -[NEVPNManager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:]
>
> Added NEVPNManager.localizedDescription
>
> Added NEVPNManager.onDemandEnabled
>
> Added NEVPNManager.onDemandRules
>
> Added NEVPNManager.protocol
>
> Added -[NEVPNManager removeFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:]
>
> Added -[NEVPNManager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:]
>
> Added +[NEVPNManager sharedManager]
>
> Added NEVPNConfigurationChangeNotification
>
> Added NEVPNError
>
> Added NEVPNErrorConfigurationDisabled
>
> Added NEVPNErrorConfigurationInvalid
>
> Added NEVPNErrorConfigurationStale
>
> Added NEVPNErrorConnectionFailed
>
> Added NEVPNErrorDomain
>
> Added #def NEVPN_EXPORT